# Invalid initialization of type when using sort

Tags: c++, sorting, initialization, std

I have the following code to sort a vector of a custom type. It used to work, but after building the code on another system it gives an error at compile time.

The context the sort() call is made.

```
std::vector<std::vector<AssemblyObject>>*     LegoAssembler::getLayers(std::vector<AssemblyObject> completeAssembly)
{    
    std::vector<std::vector<AssemblyObject>>* layers = new std::vector<std::vector<AssemblyObject>>();
    std::vector<AssemblyObject> cLayer;

    double lastZ = 0;
    std::sort(completeAssembly.begin(), completeAssembly.end(), AssemblyObject::compare);

    ...
}
```

The sorting function

```
bool AssemblyObject::compare(AssemblyObject &a, AssemblyObject &b){
return (a.getPosition()[2] < b.getPosition()[2]) ||
       ((a.getPosition()[2] == b.getPosition()[2]) && (a.getPosition()[1] > b.getPosition()[1])) ||
       ((a.getPosition()[2] == b.getPosition()[2]) && (a.getPosition()[1] == b.getPosition()[1]) && (a.getPosition()[0] > b.getPosition()[0]));
}
```

The Error

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2263: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘AssemblyObject&’ from expression of type ‘const AssemblyObject’
while (__comp(*__first, __pivot))

/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2263: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘AssemblyObject&’ from expression of type ‘const AssemblyObject’
while (__comp(*__first, __pivot))
                               ^
                               ^
```

As I said, this happened after building the code on another system. I was thinking it had something to do with changing compiler versions, but then again, I think something as simple as a sort function wouldn't break. Plus I'd like the code to compile on both compilers if that was the case.

Really would appreciate some help,

Comment: *"I think something as simple as a sort function wouldn't break"* - If you don't follow the preconditions of the algorithm, it has every right to break. In particular, note the requirement from the [prototype of the comparator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Comment: I wouldn't focus too much on the fact that it worked on another compiler. Its not uncommon for compilers to accept things they technically shouldn't, and other compilers or later releases of the same compiler might be more strict. Also, you should return the vector of vectors itself, not a pointer to it that was manually allocated.

Comment: @RyanP Thanks for the tip, will keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is attempting to take a non-const reference to a const object, which is not permitted. The compare function doesnt modify its arguments so change:

`bool AssemblyObject::compare(AssemblyObject &a, AssemblyObject &b){`

To

`bool AssemblyObject::compare(const AssemblyObject &a, const AssemblyObject &b){`

Answer (score 3):

The error is pretty clear - you need `compare` to accept `const` *lvalue-references*, not mutable ones:

```
bool AssemblyObject::compare(const AssemblyObject &a, const AssemblyObject &b)
{ 
    /* as before */
}
```